# How to use variables in all the windows forms?

Tags: c#

In my c# project i used many forms and my database is in sql server 2008.
I create one app.config file in that my connection string.

```
<add name="Courier_Management_System" connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Courier_Management_System;Integrated Security=True" />
```

now in all the forms i write the following lines for working with database

```
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
cnn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Courier_Management_System"].ToString();
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
```

so my question is if it is possible to write the above all the lines once and use it in all the forms.

Comment: Make a static class and put your logic in it

Comment: Don't use static class - it will work but is bad by design - if you want to change it in some specific cases, it will be a mess + is not possible to create unit tests for that. Use normal class instead and instantiate it everywhere you need it. It will mean one additional line of code in every form (1 for static, 2 for non static), but it is worth it!

Comment: Thank you. Where to write this static and non static class? you mean write in one additional class file ? if you have some time so any small example otherwise its ok i will understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a **class** lets say `MyDatabase` and in its `constructor` put your code as above and make these variables `public`. Now you can create object of this class and use these variables, as these will be initialized as soon as you create the object.

Example code:

```
class MyDatabase
{
 SqlConnection cnn;
 SqlDataAdapter adp;
 DataSet ds;
 DataTable dt;

 public MyDatabase()
 {
  cnn = new SqlConnection();
  cnn.ConnectionString =     ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Courier_Management_System"].ToString();
  adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
  ds = new DataSet();
  dt = new DataTable();
 }
}
```

Using this class

```
class YourForm
{
 void someMethod()
 {
  MyDatabase myDatabase = new MyDatabase();
  myDatabase.ds = //do something..
  gridView.DataSource = myDatabase.ds; //using the variable..
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.Thanks for being such a dear.

Comment: in the constructor cnn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.      this ConfigurationManager is not comes in my class file I also try and add namespace using System.Configuration;

Comment: sorry, I was away. Glad you found the answer. If your problem is solved select an answer to mark your question as solved.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do these things is to have a separate project that does the data access. But the most important idea is that you want the data access to take place in one location, e.g. in a class file like Praveen demonstrated. You can even add extra functions to execute queries and return specific resultsets, e.g.:

```
class MyDatabase
{
   SqlConnection cnn;
   SqlDataAdapter adp;
   DataSet ds;
   DataTable dt;

   public MyDatabase()
   {
      cnn = new SqlConnection();
      cnn.ConnectionString =          ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Courier_Management_System"].ToString();
      adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
      ds = new DataSet();
      dt = new DataTable();
   }

   public Dataset ExecuteQuery(string SQL)
   {
         cnn.Open();
         var ret = cnn.Execute(SQL);
         cnn.Close();
         return ret;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a static method in your Program.cs class

```
Public Static SqlConnection GetConnection()
{
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
cnn.ConnectionString = configurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Courier_Management_System"].ToString();
return cnn;
}
```

you can call this method as Program.GetConnection() where ever you want a connection object, You only need to change the connection string in only one place if there is any change.

No need to add

```
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
```

inside that method , because in most of the time you are not suppose to use those variables .